# Crash for the deletion of a database in AppData: Access denied

Tags: c#, database, path, privileges, appdata

I have this code for creating a path for a database:

```
static string folder = Application.UserAppDataPath; 
static string fisier = "prog.db"; 
string file = folder + "\\" + fisier;
```

And this code for delete the database:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(file))
   System.IO.File.Delete(file);
```

And this code for wirting the database:

```
if (!System.IO.File.Exists(file)) 
            {
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(file, "");
            }
```

The codes work perfectly, but the problem is with the privileges. To some people, is a problem with the deleting of database, the application will crash becouse will can not delete the database. Not works only for some people, in my case, work perfectly, but I want to resolve the problem to not crash if you don't have the privileges.

Comment: Minor point: Use `Path.Combine` to create the path, not string concatenation.

Comment: For me works, and for other people, but for two friends of mine don't work becouse they don't have the privileges. Why for me work, and for they, don't ?

Comment: You need to check the Active Directory Groups that you are all assigned too and permissions for the folder in which it resides.

Comment: And how I can to this automatically ? The app do the work.

Comment: You need to investiage that manually. to see why you have permissions above other users

Comment: What kind of exception are you getting? I tried running this as both admin and non admin account and this works. Is this being run on a personal computer or a domain environment that might have more restrictions?

Answer (score 0):

Error handling: try-catch is your friend.